# How do I make sure to always get the latest version of a docker image for security reasons?

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio

Some time ago I've created a ASP.NET project in Visual Studio and added Docker using its wizard.

Amongst others, the dockerfile includes this lines:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
...
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
```

Is `7.0` always the exactly same version or does this mean take latest patch version, so today that could be `7.0.1` and tomorrow `7.0.2.` even though only `7.0` is specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`7.0` is a dynamic tag that changes with every patch version. For example, as of today, all these [tags](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet/) are pointing to the same image

```
7.0.15-bullseye-slim-amd64, 7.0-bullseye-slim-amd64, 7.0.15-bullseye-slim, 7.0-bullseye-slim, 7.0.15, 7.0
```

It means `7.0` is `7.0.15`, or, more specifically, `7.0.15-bullseye-slim-amd64`.

So, using the `7.0` tag is guaranteeing(*) to use the latest patch version.

(*) It may happen that the new patch version is released, but you will still use a previous version because of the local docker cache. To ensure you always fetch the newest version, you need to execute the `docker build` command with the `--no-cach` [option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_build/#options).

Comment: Bonus detail: When using VS it will pull your base images for you on project open to make sure the cache doesn't get stale